# I can't import image in tkinter

Tags: image, tkinter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UEmx.jpg)

I want to use the path to open the image in tkitner
I tried to enter the path, but it always show error(in windows pc)
I tried the same method in my Mac and it worked
thanks

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code or errors. Take the time to copy, paste, and properly format it directly in  your question.

Comment: Change all the character "\" inside the image path to "/".

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code and errors as text rather than as screenshot(s). On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186). A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

In Python the backslash (\) escapes the main use of a character or symbol.

For instance, if you have a string `'Here\'s an string'`, the backslash tells Python the quote symbol (') is not the end of the string, but instead a part of the string, so it prints `Here's a string`.

Using two backslashes (\\) tells Python the backslash is not escaping a character or symbol, but is just a backslash in the file path. Or, like acw1668 said, you can use a forward slash (/).

```
image=PhotoImage(file="C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\example.png")
```

Comment: Or use raw string `r"..."`.